# When isn't constexpr actually a constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

Say I have the following object:

```
#include <string>

class Foo
{
public:
    constexpr Foo() {};
    constexpr std::string foo() const { return "foo"; }
};
```

This is obviously wrong, `std::string` is not a literal, cannot be returned from a `constexpr`, and the compiler complains to that effect.

However, if I make that object a template and instantiate it in my program as something arbitrary like `Foo<1>`, and then call the function, The compiler doesn't even give me so much as a warning.

```
#include <string>

template <int N>
class Foo
{
public:
    constexpr Foo() {};
    constexpr std::string foo() const { return "foo"; }
};
```

What is special about templated objects in this situation? (GCC 4.9)

Comment: Do you initialize the template at any point? As a side note, GCC 4.9 is really old, you might want to consider upgrading.

Comment: @tambre not sure, but afaik templates that cannot be valid for any `T` dont need to instantiated to cause a compiler error

Comment: Clang complains by the way.

Comment: [It's ill-formed, no diagnostic required](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.constexpr#6). So GCC doesn't emit any, but just plows through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, [this is ill-formed, and no diagnostic is required](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.constexpr#6).

Since the spec does not require diagnostics to alert writers, compilers don't *have* to do anything if you write this code, and the compiler is free to ignore the fact that the user thinks that their code should be able to be evaluated at compile time and carry on its merry way.

Now, if you're like me you're probably thinking "wait... why?  This seems like the perfect case for a warning at the very least since what I wrote  won't result in exactly what I expect."

This, apparently, is what the developers of clang thought too, so even though this code could go through compilation cleanly according to the letter of the law, clang throws full-blown errors:

- [gcc compiles fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LOFkKGq3xzGhdgIj)
- [clang does not](https://wandbox.org/permlink/e8IsCbI217wA9uZg)

Comment: The code doesn't have to go through compilation cleanly according to the letter of the law. Throwing errors is also perfectly compliant behaviour in this case.

Comment: changed should to could